# What type of connector is this

Tags: connector

I've bought a 12VDC pump for a CNC machine I'm building. I want to get a connector that will fit this plug so that I can run it from my power supply source.

The problem is that I don't know what these connectors are called in order to buy a suitable plug.

Anyone know what this type of connector is called?

[image: 12V pump connector]
[image: 12V pump connector 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always indicate the pitch (spacing between pins), when asking for a connector identification.

Anyway, I am pretty sure it is 2.54 mm and these are **2510 series** connectors (a part number originally from a company named OST: [datasheet](http://www.on-shore.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/ipg36.pdf)). You can find a lot of those on ebay/alibaba (just google "2510 connector"). But it is actually difficult to find a "reputable" vendor offering exactly those.

However, they should be compatible with [Molex KK](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=kk_254_rpc_connector_system&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=wire_to_board_connectors) series.

Comment: Well done, @dim :) How did you know it was an OST knock-off instead of a Molex KK?

Comment: @bitsmack because the polarizing ribs on Molex KK are much shorter: see [molex datasheet](http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/022012035_sd.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a free-hanging rectangular connector with a polarizing key. The key assured the plug can't be installed backwards. You'll need to measure to get the exact spacing between the pins, but it looks like 0.100".

If the pitch is 0.100", you have lots of options for plugging as this is the standard breadboard / jumper pitch as well.