# Can anyone ID this 3 pin plug?

Tags: identification, plug

This connector is out of a Sega Dreamcast. I need a new wiring harness but can't find out what this plug is.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The plug is 6.54mm wide, 3.42mm high (excluding the "key" 4.08 with the key), 6.48mm deep.

I can just about make out the letters JST, but very small.  I can't get the camera to focus.

Comment: try to look for it on the Molex website

Comment: I have had a look but cant seem to find one the same :(

Comment: @Titchg If you want to increase chances for getting an useful answer add exact dimensions and look out for manufacturer symbols and features like the first pin designation. Post pictures of embossed numbers and symbols. (My bet is J.S.T.)

Comment: Thanks Ariser ile get on that now....
Original post updated.

Comment: And inline your images. Most of us don't have time to follow links just to see what the question is about. You might be limited to two images inline because you are new. Someone will fix up the other one for you.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to make them inline?
I have updated with sizes and marks.

Comment: @Titchg Try a search for "jst 3 pin connector".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What type of connector is this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/287934/what-type-of-connector-is-this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone is looking for a dreamcast fan plug in the future I can confirm it is a JST PH.

Thanks everyone.